# Prove that a ring homomorphism is one to one if and only if the field F is infinite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $F$ be a field and $A$ be the set of all function from $F$ to $F$. Define $E:F[x]\to A$ by mapping $p(x)\in F[x]$ to the function computed using the given polynomial.

I have shown that such a function $E$ is a homomorphism, but how do I show that it is one-to-one if and only if the field $F$ is infinite?

Answer (score 2):

Hint: A polynomial $p(x)\in F[x]$ is in the kernel of $E$ iff every element of $F$ is a root of $p$.  How many roots can a polynomial have?

Comment: Number of roots is deg(p)..

Comment: Can you please elaborate a bit more? I am not sure how your hint connects to the problem yet

Comment: A nonzero polynomial over a field has at most $\deg(p)$ roots.  If $F$ is infinite, can you have a polynomial that has every element of $F$ as a root?  Conversely, if you have any finite set $\{a_1,\dots,a_n\}\subset F$, can you find a polynomial that has all of them as roots?

Comment: Answer to first question is no, and I can find the polynomial which will be $(x-a_1)(x-a_2)...(x-a_n)$ as answer to your second question?